# Transcendental number definition query

Tags: transcendental-numbers

The wiki page says that a transcendental number is defined as "a number that is not the root of a non-zero polynomial with rational coefficients".  When they provide this definition, shouldn't they add that the polynomial order has to be finite also?

Comment: Polynomials have finite order, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Any polynomial is by definition of finite order, so it’s not necessary to include it in the definition. If it has infinite order, then it is a Taylor series or something similar, and not a polynomial.